# Show data instead of object in form value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a vue.js component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" v-for="select in selected" :name="prpName + '[]'" :value="select">

        <multiselect
                v-model="selected"
        </multiselect>
    </div>
</template>
```

I use this in blade:

```
<multiselect></multiselect>
```

The problem now is that when I submit the form in my request I see this:

```
"relations_internal" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "[object Object]"
  ]
```

But I want not an object but the **real** data. I know this is a newbie question but I can't figured it out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue.js, but does [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) work for you?

Comment: Well depens on what `select` is - you should use it's value or whatever multiselect returns

Comment: @AndreyPopov Yes I understand that but I want to return the full object.

Comment: Well you want the full object, but you sent it over the network - you cannot expect it to automatically convert into something. As @LyingCake said - you should use some kind of serialization (and deserialization on backend) in order to achieve that. But it is highly NOT recommended - it's easier to send the ID only ;)

Comment: Is `multiselect` a component you created or something you imported?